# export same values in specific columns of an excel file and add them to a new column using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have an excel file that according to users input , add columns called "cellname".
for example:  if user tells 3, i would have 3 columns called "cellname"

**what i am looking for :** find the values in cellname columns , that are same and then add them into new coulmn called: result

**strong text**this the code till now

```
import pandas as pd
import os

v=int(input("how many periods do you have:\n"))
new_excel_by_user = str(input("Write the name of your new EXCEL file: "))
user_excel = pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')


sys_excel = pd.ExcelWriter('sys_excel11.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

merged_df_H = pd.DataFrame()
merged_df_L = pd.DataFrame()


for i in range(v):
  print("\nPeriod %d :" % (i+1))

excelpathH = input("Insert your Excel path (HIGH): ")
excelpathL = input("Insert your Excel path (LOW): ")

excelpathH = excelpathH.replace('"', '')
excelpathL = excelpathL.replace('"', '')

dfH = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathH), engine='openpyxl')
dfL = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathL), engine='openpyxl')

#merged_df_H=merged_df_H.merge(dfH,how='inner',on='Azimuth')

azi=dfH['CELL_FIRST_ANTENNA_AZIMUTH']
merged_df_H['azi']=azi
azi=merged_df_H['azi']

lat=dfH['LATITUDE']
merged_df_H['LATITUDE']=lat
lat=merged_df_H['LATITUDE']

long=dfH['LONGITUDE']
merged_df_H['LONGITUDE']=long
long=merged_df_H['LONGITUDE']

bsc=dfH['BSC_RNC_NAME']
merged_df_H['BSC_RNC_NAME']=bsc
bsc=merged_df_H['BSC_RNC_NAME']


Rnh=dfH['KPI VALUE']
#Rnh=dfH['KPIVALUE']

# for rrr in dfL:
Rnl=dfL['KPI VALUE']
#Rnl=dfL['KPIVALUE']

R=Rnh-Rnl
merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)]=R
R=merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)]

merged_df_H['CellName%s'%(i+1)]=dfH['CELL_NAME']
merged_df_H['CellName']=merged_df_H['CellName%s'%(i+1)]

#SN=merged_df_H['ss%s'%(i+1)]

mask1 = merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)].ge(3)

R = merged_df_H.filter(like='R').melt()['value']
SN = merged_df_H.filter(like='CellName').melt()['value']
azim=merged_df_H.filter(like='CELL_FIRST_ANTENNA_AZIMUTH').melt()['value']
mask = SN.duplicated(keep=False)





merged_df_H = pd.concat([merged_df_H.loc[mask1]],
                      axis=1)

### merged_df_H = pd.concat([merged_df_H,RESULT], axis=1)

# out = merged_df_H.join(pd.concat([SN[mask], R[mask]], 
         #          axis=1, 
         #          keys=('SN-RESULT','R-RESULT')).reset_index(drop=True))




print(merged_df_H)

# Write merged dataframes to a new Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as user_excel:
 merged_df_H.to_excel(user_excel, sheet_name='High', index=False)
```

**EXPOER THE CELLVALUES WHERE CELLNAME IS GREATER THAN 10:**

**WHAT I HAVE :**
[image]

---

**WHAT I WANT :**
**EXPOER THE CELLVALUES WHERE CELLNAME IS GREATER THAN 10:**

[image]

Comment: Please add sample of input and expected output. It will make helping you easier

Comment: do you means the same values in the same row? Better show example data and expected result, and explain why you need this result,

Comment: pandas has function `.count()` to count value in column - if value is repeated in column then `count` should give value bigger than `1`. There is also function `.uniq()` - if all values are the same then it should give only one value.

Comment: shorter `azi = merged_df_H['azi'] = dfH['CELL_FIRST_ANTENNA_AZIMUTH']`

Comment: @furas yes, i mean export the same vlues which are in roows of columns named :"cellname"

Comment: normally I would convert data to `set()` and use `set(list_1) & set(list_2) & set(list_3)` to get elements which are repeated in all lists `

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is function in `Excel` or `Pandas` for this.
Maybe `df.isin()` could solve it but I will use standard `set()` for this.

First it would need to convert rows to lists

```
a = [(15,"A"),(2,"B"),(3,"C"), (9,"D"),(11,"E"),(6,"F"),(19,"H"),(12,"T")]
b = [(8,"T"),(15,"A"),(10,"C"),(1,"D"),(4,"T"),(11,"E"),(13,"G"),(19,"H")]
c = [(15,"A"),(5,"R"),(4,"T"),(1,"T"),(11,"E"),(25,"L"),(19,"H"),(13,"T")]
```

and later it needs to use `set()` and operation `&`

```
result = set(a) & set(b) & set(c)  # set

#result = list(result)  # convert to list
```

Result:

```
{(11, 'E'), (15, 'A'), (19, 'H')}   # set
 
#[(11, 'E'), (15, 'A'), (19, 'H')]  # converted to list
```

There is only one problem - it doesn't have to give values in the same order.